# Docx missing attributes

Tags: python, python-2.7, docx

I'm trying to do anything considering word document using docx library in python. The problem is, whatever I import, I get error message about 'no attribute'. For eample - Document

```
from docx import Document
```

gives output

```
cannot import name Document
```

and any try to use Document ends with error

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Document'
```

Any syntax seems to be correct. I'm using docx module version 0.2.4 .

Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [official documentation](http://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/install.html)

> python-docx versions 0.3.0 and later are not API-compatible with prior versions.

so, try to update package or use old [api](https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx/tree/v0.2.0)

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem. I had used `pip install docx` in my virtual environment. The fix was to `pip uninstall docx` and then `pip install python-docx`.

Answer (score 1):

are you sure you properly installed `docx`? Because it seems it is not installed.
You should try using `pip` or `easy_install` to install it properly.

http://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/install.html

For example, I never installed it and I get this following code error if I try to import it which is pretty much what you get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docx.py", line 1, in <module>
  from docx import Document
File "/Users/xxxx/Documents/Python/docx.py", line 1, in <module>
from docx import Document
ImportError: cannot import name Document
```