# Unable to install python-docx (MacOS)

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, importerror, python-docx

I am trying to install `docx` package. but getting the following `ImportError`:

`ImportError: cannot import name Document`

So as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41655815/10293797), I tried :

`pip install python-docx`
but getting the following error (python version: 2.7.15)

```
..
..
..

    creating build/lib/docx/templates
    copying docx/templates/default-header.xml -> build/lib/docx/templates
    copying docx/templates/default-settings.xml -> build/lib/docx/templates
    copying docx/templates/default-footer.xml -> build/lib/docx/templates
    error: can't copy 'docx/templates/default-docx-template': doesn't exist or not a regular file 
    Command 

 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -u -c "import  

setuptools,tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/0c/v_yb4q7n2h3fg94rlfrr165r0000gn/T/pip-build-ks26RP/python-docx/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',  

'\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/0c/v_yb4q7n2h3fg94rlfrr165r0000gn/T/pip-1SQvtb-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/0c/v_yb4q7n2h3fg94rlfrr165r0000gn/T/pip-build-ks26RP/python-docx/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a problem installing `python-docx` in certain environments in the recently released v0.8.9. Installing v0.8.10 should rectify that for most users. If installation still fails (on certain Linux versions), updating setuptools has been reported to fix it:

```
$ pip install -U setuptools
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to install packages with `pip` you need to use `sudo` unless you are installing to a user directory. So it would be;

```
sudo pip install python-docx
```

You could also [download the package from pypi](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e4/83/c66a1934ed5ed8ab1dbb9931f1779079f8bca0f6bbc5793c06c4b5e7d671/python-docx-0.8.10.tar.gz) untar it, cd into untared directory and run;

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

Updating setuptools to latest version may also be needed.

Comment: None of the above worked. Throwing the same error `error: can't copy 'docx/templates/default-docx-template': doesn't exist or not a regular file` . Is it something related to mac os?  I have installed using `sudo pip install python-docx` on my Unix based system, there it works fine.

Comment: Updating `setuptools` to latest version and installing `python-docx` worked. Thanks :)

Comment: I updated my answer as you replied with updating setuptools lol

Comment: Btw Jack, installing Python packages using `sudo` is probably not a terrific idea as it modifies the system Python installation. Generally when that "fixes" a problem there's something else wrong with the Python installation that is better remedied at its root cause. More on that here (and on search): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028648/is-it-acceptable-and-safe-to-run-pip-install-under-sudo

Comment: @scanny, "You only use sudo or elevated permissions when you want to install stuff for the global, system-wide Python installation".. in 5 years of python development I have yet to have issues installing packages globally, plus it encouraged me to learn where and how python  packages are installed so that manual rollbacks are simple. On top of that I feel that install several versions of the same package to be a very strange behaviour - I tend to have several python versions on my system all with there own packages and all globally installed packages. I guess its an each to there own situation

Answer (score 0):

For `python2.7`, pip installer downloads source for `python-docx` which requires to be complied, c++ build tools are required for the compilation process. `xcode command line tools` provides required libraries for c++ sources to be compiled. To install `xcode command line tools`, use following command:

```
xcode-select --install
```

After `xcode command line tools`, use pip install `python-docx` again, this time compilation process should complete without any error and you will have `python-docx` installed on your system.

Comment: command line tools were already installed. Issue might be something related to `setuptools`. After updating  `setuptools`, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Updating setup tools worked for me to.

I did a:

`sudo easy_install -U setuptools`

Then installed it again and it worked fine.